# Append a Range to Log (Txt) file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to append a range from `"A2:B" & LastRow` to a log txt file with a `;` delimiter.

For now I know how to read from separate cells but not from `"A2:B"`

Column `A` = text

Column `B2:B` = `=IF(A2="","",1)`

My code:

```
Dim strData As String
Dim strLine As String
strData = ""
Open "\\x-ap01\Log.txt" For Input As #1
While EOF(1) = False
    Line Input #1, strLine
    strData = strData + strLine & vbCrLf
Wend

strData = strData + Cells(2, 1) & ";" & Cells(2, 2) & ";"    

Close #1
Open "\\x-ap01\Log.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, strData
Close #1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
Sub x()

Dim strData As String
Dim strLine As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Open "\\x-ap01\Log.txt" For Append As #1

For r = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(r, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        strData = strData & Cells(r, 1) & ";" & Cells(r, 2) & ";"
        strData = strData & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Next r

Print #1, strData
Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: After the cell input it sets `;` delimiters until end of file (+/- 1000lines), but I forget to mention there is a formula in the B Cells until Row 1000

Comment: And you want to exclude them - are these formulae returning blanks? Does column A extend as far down with formulae too?

Comment: The formula returns blanks if row `A` is blank (`vlookup A`)

Comment: So you just want the data in A and B in which the formulae do not return blanks?

Comment: I need just the values in A & B, skipping blanks with or without formulae

Comment: Amended above, but better to limit the formulae if possible.

Comment: This strangly enough keeps copying my data from A and B to the log, repeating until 1000xCell count in A

Comment: Can you post the formula?

Comment: The Formula in B  `=IF(A2="","",1)`

Comment: I can't replicate that, but have made a couple of changes above.

Comment: 1st run A1 = a, A2 = b, A3 = c | 2nd run A1 = x A2 = y, A3 = z

Comment: logfile: `QR Codes;Quantity;QR Codes;Quantity;
x;1;QR Codes;Quantity;
y;1;QR Codes;Quantity;
z;1;QR Codes;Quantity;
QR Codes;Quantity;a;1;
x;1;a;1;
y;1;a;1;
z;1;a;1;
QR Codes;Quantity;b;1;
x;1;b;1;
y;1;b;1;
z;1;b;1;
QR Codes;Quantity;c;1;
x;1;c;1;
y;1;c;1;
z;1;c;1;
QR Codes;Quantity;
x;1;
y;1;
z;1;`

Comment: Try again - this appends to the file.